# Proof for $\forall k >0 $, $\{(x,y) : |xy| > k^2\} \subset \{(x,y) : |x| > k \ \ or \ \ |y| > k \}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show, $\forall k >0 $, the following holds.

$$
\{(x,y) : |xy| > k^2\} \subset \{(x,y) : |x| > k \ \ or \ \ |y| > k \}
$$

I'm failing to figure out a contradiction.

Is there anyone to give a contradiction / proof for the statement?

How about when $k \ge 1$?

Comment: If $|xy| > k^2$ then $|x| > \frac {k^2}{|y|}$.  If $|y| \le k$ then $|x| > \frac {k^2}{|y|}\ge \frac {k^2}{k} = k$.  If $|y| > k$ then $|y| > k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If$$\{(x,y)\,|\,|xy| > k^2\} \not\subset \{(x,y) \,|\, |x| > k\text{ or }|y| > k \},$$then there would be a $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|xy|>k^2$ and that both numbers $|x|$ and $|y|$ are smaller than or equal to $k$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the math.  $|xy| > k^2 \implies |x| > \frac {k^2}{|y|}$ and $|y| > \frac {k^2}{|x|}$ and if $|x| \le k$ then $|y| > \frac {k^2}{|x|} \ge \frac {k^2}{k} = k$.  And if $|y| \le k$ then $|x| > \frac {k^2}{|x|} \ge \frac {k^2}{k} = k$.

Basically when ever you have $ab > M > 0$ then either $|a| > \sqrt M$ or $|b| > \sqrt M$.